# Can I use the Google Maps API used for real estate web app?

Tags: google-maps, web-applications, google-maps-api-3

I'd like to create a web app something like Zillow.com but not in the US. I'm wondering if I can use the Google Maps API for free for that and if not, what are cheap alternatives to get me started? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use OpenStreetMap in commercial products. All you have to do is quote them as the source of your map data.

You can find the detailed license information here: http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Google Maps API for free if your maps api implementation is publicly available (free).  If not, you must purchase a [Google Maps API for Business License](https://developers.google.com/maps/licensing).

The following is taken from the free [Google Maps API license](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_9_1):

> (a) Free Access (No Fees). Your Maps API Implementation must be
>   generally accessible to users without charge and must not require a
>   fee-based subscription or other fee-based restricted access. This rule
>   applies to Your Content and any other content in your Maps API
>   Implementation, whether Your Content or the other content is in
>   existence now or is added later.
>
> (b) Public Access (No Firewall). Your Maps API implementation must not
>   operate (i) only behind a firewall; or (ii) only on an internal
>   network (except during the development and testing phase); or (iii) in
>   a closed community (for example, through invitation-only access).

If the Google Maps licenses won't work for you, you could use [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/).